# Is there a planned release date for sonarqube 5.2?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Apparently, SonarQube 5.2 won't need a connection string to push build data. (I discovered this by having a look at the sonar.runner vso-build-tasks earlier this morning).

When will this version be available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SonarQube 5.2 is expected late October 2015 / early November 2015.

**Update**: SonarQube 5.2 was released on November 2th, 2015.